# Reduce Mongo's DB size for storing tweets

Tags: mongodb

I need to store millions of tweets for a project. Currently I'm at 9,5 million tweets (inserting ~ 40 per second from twitter's sample stream). MongoDB's database size for the "tweets" collection is 22GB.

Since I'm planning on getting many millions more, I'm wondering if there is any configuration option I overlooked, since I just installed mongo and ran the server "as is".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your collection "schema" look like? If all you're storing is tweet text that DB is a magnitude larger than one would expect.

Comment: Mongo pre-allocates the diskspace. read this http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space

Comment: Indeed. The difference between the size of the data you're storing and the amount of data it takes on disk is almost completely related to your document schema and the indexes you defined for that collection. If you share those we might be able to provide you with an answer. Also note that since MongoDB is schemaless it will always store the field name for every field. Just reducing the size of the field names can actually have a big impact on data size.

Comment: @Pangea, that would at most cause 2GB overhead. He's at 22GB which averages out at 2.3KB per tweet. For 140 characters and an author name that's a bit much to be explained by just preallocation.

Comment: I'm receiving the tweets as a json object and sending them directly to the DB. Any other info you guys want to know? Validate command or another one? I'm storing everything about the tweet, not just user and message, since I can't fall behind when receiving the tweets from the stream (can't waste time removing fields).

Comment: I guess with all the other tweet info the size is normal then. When I reach the number of tweets I want, i'll try and remove the fields that dont matter.